# Gridview, itextsharp and pdf

Tags: asp.net, pdf, gridview

Using itextsharp.dll as a reference and the Gridview defined before the code below I keep getting the error:

```
The document has no pages.
```

Here is the code:

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=this.pdf")
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    Dim frm As New HtmlForm()
    GridView1.AllowPaging = False
    GridView1.Parent.Controls.Add(frm)
    frm.Attributes("runat") = "server"
    frm.Controls.Add(GridView1)
    frm.RenderControl(hw)
    Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
    Dim PDFdoc As New Document(PageSize.A2, 7.0F, 7.0F, 7.0F, 0.0F)
    Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(PDFdoc)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(PDFdoc, Response.OutputStream)
    PDFdoc.Open()
    htmlparser.Parse(sr)
    PDFdoc.Close()
    Response.Write(PDFdoc)
    Response.[End]()
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of `sr` is either empty or `HTMLWorker` cannot able to interpret the `HTML` that it contains.

**Note**: Also, `HTMLWorker` class is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  GridView1.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter's object)
```

know more [here](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-export-GridView-data-to-PDF-file-in-ASPNet.aspx)